# oracle plsql cursor error

Tags: plsql, cursor

i am having a table called req_tb

```
CREATE TABLE req_tb(TableName   VARCHAR2(43),
                    ColumnName  VARCHAR2(98),
                    Edit_ind    CHAR)
/
```

i am inserting values as

```
insert into req_tb VALUES('Employees','employee_id      ','Y');
insert into req_tb VALUES('Employees','first_name       ','Y');
insert into req_tb VALUES('Employees','last_name        ','N');
insert into req_tb VALUES('Employees','email            ','N');
insert into req_tb VALUES('Employees','job_id           ','N');
insert into req_tb VALUES('Employees','salary           ','Y');
insert into req_tb VALUES('Employees','commission_pct   ','Y');
insert into req_tb VALUES('Employees','hire_date        ','N');
insert into req_tb VALUES('Employees','department_id    ','Y');
```

now my table as below

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM REQ_TB;

TABLENAME                                   COLUMNNAME      EDIT_IND
------------------------------------------- --------------- ----------
Employees                                   employee_id     Y
Employees                                   first_name      Y
Employees                                   last_name       N
Employees                                   email           N
Employees                                   job_id          N
Employees                                   salary          Y
Employees                                   commission_pct  Y
Employees                                   hire_date       N
Employees                                   department_id   Y
```

consider column edit_ind is changing dynamically in table req_tb and i want to print only the columns who are makes as 'Y'. please check my procedure for this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE dyn_sql_sp
AS
 cols     VARCHAR2(2000);
 v_cols   VARCHAR2(2000);
 cls      VARCHAR2(2000);
 v_employee_id number;
 emp       employees%rowtype;
 cnt       number;
cursor tab_c
is
 select columnname from req_tb
 where EDIT_IND='Y';
cursor col_c
is
 select employee_id from employees;
BEGIN
for i in tab_C
loop
cols:=cols||'emp.'||i.columnname||'||';
end loop;
cols:=rtrim(cols,'||');
for i in col_c
loop
SELECT * into emp from employees
where employee_id=i.employee_id;
dbms_output.put_line(cols);
end loop;
 Exception
 When Others Then
 dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm||sqlcode);
 end;
/
```

i expected output as

```
100 Steven                    24000                           90
101 Neena                     17000                           90
102 Lex                        17000                           90
103 Alexander                  9000                           60
104 Bruce                      6000                           60
105 David                      4800                           60
106 Valli                      4800                         60
107 Diana                      4200                           60
```

output im getting is

```
SQL> exec dyn_sql_sp;
emp.employee_id         ||emp.first_name                ||emp.salary                    ||emp.commission_pct   ||emp.department_id
emp.employee_id         ||emp.first_name                ||emp.salary                    ||emp.commission_pct   ||emp.department_id
emp.employee_id         ||emp.first_name                ||emp.salary                    ||emp.commission_pct   ||emp.department_id
emp.employee_id         ||emp.first_name                ||emp.salary                    ||emp.commission_pct   ||emp.department_id
emp.employee_id         ||emp.first_name                ||emp.salary                    ||emp.commission_pct   ||emp.department_id
emp.employee_id         ||emp.first_name                ||emp.salary                    ||emp.commission_pct   ||emp.department_id
emp.employee_id         ||emp.first_name                ||emp.salary                    ||emp.commission_pct   ||emp.department_id
emp.employee_id         ||emp.first_name                ||emp.salary                    ||emp.commission_pct   ||emp.department_id
emp.employee_id         ||emp.first_name                ||emp.salary                    ||emp.commission_pct   ||emp.department_id
emp.employee_id         ||emp.first_name                ||emp.salary                    ||emp.commission_pct   ||emp.department_id
emp.employee_id         ||emp.first_name                ||emp.salary                    ||emp.commission_pct   ||emp.department_id
```

what is the mistake

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem:

```
for i in col_c
loop
SELECT * into emp from employees
where employee_id=i.employee_id;
dbms_output.put_line(cols);
end loop;
```

You are selecting everything `*` (so every column) from `employes` table and you are never using it. What you want is to select only column being in the `cols` variable. To do this you should use dynamic statement, something like this:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT ' || cols || ' FROM employees WHERE emplyee_id = :1'
INTO emp
USING i.employee_id
```

But then there is another problem. Cursor `emp` from the dynamic statement is not of type `employees%rowtype` (different number of columns), so dynamic statement will fail.

Fortunately it seems that DBMS_SQL package can help you. Please see this post: https://community.oracle.com/thread/702648, there you should find a solution for this problem.